# socket disconnection notification method

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, disconnect

just searched for a posibble solution to indetify when the client disconnecets.
i found this:

```
        public bool IsConnected( Socket s)
    {
        try
        {
            return !(s.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) &&s.Available == 0);
        }
        catch (SocketException) { return false; }
    }
```

im using a while loop in my main with thread.sleep(500) and running the Isconnectedmthod it works allright when i run it through the visual studio and when i click stop debugging it actually notify me in the server side program but when i just go to the exe in the bin directory and launch it-it's Indeed notify me for a connection but when i close the program (manually from the 'x' button) or through the task manager the`IsConnected` method apparently return still true..... 
im using a simple tcp connection

```
        client = new TcpClient();
         client.Connect("10.0.0.2", 10);
```

server:

```
Socket s = tcpClient.Client;
        while(true)
        {

            if (!IsConnected(s))


                MessageBox.Show("disconnected");
        }
```

(it's running on a thread btw).

any suggestion guys?
i even tried to close the connection when the client closes:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

        client.Close();
        s.Close();
        Environment.Exit(0);

    }
```

dont know what to do

Comment: Haven't you seen the very many answers on this problem that tell you that this is impossible? You are not the first one to try to detect TCP connection loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible. TCP will not report an error on the connection unless an attempt is made to *send* on the connection. If all your program ever does is receive, it will never notice that the connection no longer exists.

There are some platform-dependent exceptions to this rule, but none involving the simple disappearance of the remote endpoint.

The correct way for a client to disconnect is for it to gracefully close the connection with a "shutdown" operation. In .NET, this means the client code calls `Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)`. The client must then continue to receive until the server calls `Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)`. Note that the shutdown "reason" is generally "send" for the endpoint initiating the closure, and "both" for the endpoint acknowledging and completing the closure.

Each endpoint will detect that the other endpoint has shutdown its end by the completion of a receive operation with `0` as the byte count return value for that operation. Neither endpoint should actually *close* the socket (i.e. call `Socket.Close()`) until this two-way graceful closure has completed. I.e. each endpoint has both called `Socket.Shutdown()` *and* seen a zero-byte receive operation completion.

The above is how graceful closure works, and it should be the norm for server/client interactions. Of course, things do break. A client could crash, the network might be disconnected, etc. Typically, the right thing to do is to delay recognition of such problems as long as possible; for example, as long as the server and client have no need to actually communicate, then a temporary network outage should not cause an error. Forcing one is pointless in that case.

In other words, don't add code to try to detect a connection failure. For maximum reliability, let the network try to recover on its own.

In some less-common cases, it is desirable to detect connection failures earlier. In these cases, you can enable "keep alive" on the socket (to force data to be sent over the connection, thus detecting interruptions in the connection…see [`SocketOptionName.KeepAlive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname(v=vs.110).aspx)) or implement some timeout mechanism (to force the connection to fail if no data is sent after some period of time). I would generally recommend against the use of this kind of technique, but it's a valid approach in some cases.